# Integrating Sqlite3 with MFC VS2012

Tags: sqlite, visual-studio-2012

Im developing small size MFC VC++ app. For that i need to integrate Sqlite3 with existing MFC app.

I surfed net and found some tutorials which are not working for me.

So kindly let me know the steps.

PS: i have downloaded source code and libs and dll from sqlite.org website. and Im using VS2012.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks,Selva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I configured my VS2012 successfully.
These are the steps i have followed.
1.Download sqlite3.dll,sqlite3.h,sqlite3.exp and sqlite3.def from sqlite web.
2.create sqlite3.lib from .def file using LIB command. Navigate to vs 2012 installation /bin to find LIB file to run the command.
3.Create a new project in vs2012 workspace and copy the sqlite3.h,sqlite3.exp and sqlite.lib to your project files location.
4.create a new folder any of your drive and copy the dll,lib and exp.
5.Right click->properties of your project and add the dll folder as the additional libraries. thats it.

Your ready to program sqlite including sqlite3.h in cpp files.

Thank you.